# swift function return multiple values

Tags: ios, swift, function

Below is a function that I am trying to create that will get the values in JSON data based on the key value entered. The problem I am having is I need Need to be able to use all the rates in another calculation. I am not sure how to get each rate saved to a global variable. At this point, the function is giving me an error - "Missing Return in a function expecting to return a string". Any ideas how to solve this problem

```
   func getLenderData(selectedLenderKey: String) -> String
    {

        let url = ""
        var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: url)!)
        request.httpMethod = "GET"

        let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
        let session = URLSession(configuration: configuration, delegate: nil, delegateQueue: OperationQueue.main)

        let task = session.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
            if error != nil {
                print("Error")
            }
            else{

                do{
                    //let fetchedData = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableLeaves) as! NSArray
                    //print(fecthdata)

                    let swiftyJSON = try JSON(data:data!)
                    let lenderName = swiftyJSON["lenders"][selectedLenderKey]["financial_institution"].stringValue
                    let oneYear = swiftyJSON["lenders"][selectedLenderKey]["one_year"].stringValue
                    let twoYear = swiftyJSON["lenders"][selectedLenderKey]["two_year"].stringValue
                    let threeYear = swiftyJSON["lenders"][selectedLenderKey]["three_year"].stringValue
                    let fourYear = swiftyJSON["lenders"][selectedLenderKey]["four_year"].stringValue
                    let fiveYear = swiftyJSON["lenders"][selectedLenderKey]["five_year"].stringValue


                    print(lenderName)
                    print(oneYear)
                    print(twoYear)
                    print(threeYear)
                    print(fourYear)
                    print(fiveYear)


                }

                catch{
                    print("Error 2")
                }
            }

        }
        task.resume()
    }// end function
```

Comment: The error comes from you not returning any value. If you ask me, I would create a struct like @Rashwan L did in his answer however instead of a return type create a completion handler, this is a recommended approach for async functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a model and return that model:

```
struct Rates {
    let lenderName: String?
    let oneYear: String?
    let twoYear: String?
    let threeYear: String?
    let fourYear: String?
    let fiveYear: String?

    required init() {
        lenderName = nil
        oneYear = nil
        twoYear = nil
        threeYear = nil
        fourYear = nil
        fiveYear = nil
    }

    init(lenderName: String?, oneYear: String?, twoYear: String?, threeYear: String?, fourYear: String?, fiveYear: String?) {
        self.lenderName = lenderName
        self.oneYear = oneYear
        self.twoYear = twoYear
        self.threeYear = threeYear
        self.fourYear = fourYear
        self.fiveYear = fiveYear
    }
}
```

Then return the model you created:

```
func getLenderData(selectedLenderKey: String, onCompletion: @escaping (Rates?) -> Void, onError: @escaping (NSError) -> Void) {
    let url = ""
    var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: url)!)
    request.httpMethod = "GET"

    let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
    let session = URLSession(configuration: configuration, delegate: nil, delegateQueue: OperationQueue.main)

    let task = session.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
        if error != nil {
            print("Error")
        }
        else{

            do{
                //let fetchedData = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableLeaves) as! NSArray
                //print(fecthdata)

                let swiftyJSON = try JSON(data:data!)
                let lenderName = swiftyJSON["lenders"][selectedLenderKey]["financial_institution"].stringValue
                let oneYear = swiftyJSON["lenders"][selectedLenderKey]["one_year"].stringValue
                let twoYear = swiftyJSON["lenders"][selectedLenderKey]["two_year"].stringValue
                let threeYear = swiftyJSON["lenders"][selectedLenderKey]["three_year"].stringValue
                let fourYear = swiftyJSON["lenders"][selectedLenderKey]["four_year"].stringValue
                let fiveYear = swiftyJSON["lenders"][selectedLenderKey]["five_year"].stringValue



                print(lenderName)
                print(oneYear)
                print(twoYear)
                print(threeYear)
                print(fourYear)
                print(fiveYear)

                let rate = Rates(lenderName: lenderName, oneYear: oneYear, twoYear: twoYear, threeYear: threeYear, fourYear: fourYear, fiveYear: fiveYear)
                onCompletion(rate)


            }

            catch{
                print("Error 2")
                onError(NSError(domain: "Some error description...", code: 0, userInfo: nil))
            }
        }

    }
    task.resume()
}// end function
```

Now you can just use the `return value` as you want. To use it use the following code:

```
getLenderData(selectedLenderKey: "someVal", onCompletion: { (rate) in
   // you can use the rate here
   let oneYear = rate.oneYear
}, onError: { (error) in
    // Error
})
```

Comment: It will still throw the same error as you don't return a value for every state, this is why I would recommend a completion handler instead of a return type.

Comment: @J.Paravicini, you´re right, I updated the answer and added a completionHandler.

Comment: Thank you for the replies, I am getting an error message: required initializer is non-class type. at this line of code "required init() {" I removed required and the error went away, but I am still getting no results. the result returned is ***Optional("")****. The code made me at a ? after rate on the script to call the function.

Comment: @KevinProctor, do you get any data from `let lenderName = swiftyJSON["lenders"][selectedLenderKey]["financial_institution"].stringValue` for example?

Comment: Yes. I created a function before I tried passing a value through it. Here is sample code that returns the correct value. let "fiveYear = swiftyJSON["lenders"][20]["five_year"].stringValue" The function I posted is to replace the value 20 with a variable "selectedLenderKey".I can print the value of the variable [selectedLenderKey] outside the function. Swift also made me change your code to: let selectedOneYear = rate!.oneYear. The "!' is the new part. It's like when the function is called it does not recognize the variable value.

Comment: I have figured a little more out: JSON Snippet: {"key":"99","financial_institution":"DUCA Financial Services","variable_rate":"2.35","six_months":"0","one_year":"3.04","two_year":"2.94","three_year":"2.94","four_year":"3.14","five_year":"2.79","date":"2017-06-05"}, the variable I am passing through the function is supposed to be searching for the key value. I think the function is search for the postion of values in the array parased from JSON.

Comment: @KevinProctor, is it possible for you to zip the project and send a link to from Dropbox or Google Drive and I´ll take a look at your project and try to help you?

Comment: So if I understand your issue, you want to pass data to `secondViewController` when you press the Mortgage penalty Calculator button?

Comment: Yes. When the user selects the Leander. I need the interest rates for that lender stored in variables do I can use them in formulas

Comment: Where do I find the project you helped fixed?

Comment: @KevinProctor, I posted the link in our AppearIn chat yesterday but seem to have missed it. Anyway [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/wdzm09fjqr9yeno/Canadian%20Mortgage%20Tools.zip?dl=0) it is. Good luck!

Comment: Got it. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use `Promise` for this sort of implementation. Look into [PromiseKit](https://github.com/mxcl/PromiseKit). Your code would become something like this

```
func getLenderData(selectedLenderKey: String) -> Promise<String> {
    return Promise { fulfill, reject in
        let url = ""
    var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: url)!)
    request.httpMethod = "GET"

    let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
    let session = URLSession(configuration: configuration, delegate: nil, delegateQueue: OperationQueue.main)

    let task = session.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
        if error != nil {
            print("Error")
            reject({ERROR})
        }
        else{

            do{
                //let fetchedData = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableLeaves) as! NSArray
                //print(fecthdata)

                let swiftyJSON = try JSON(data:data!)
                let lenderName = swiftyJSON["lenders"][selectedLenderKey]["financial_institution"].stringValue
                let oneYear = swiftyJSON["lenders"][selectedLenderKey]["one_year"].stringValue
                let twoYear = swiftyJSON["lenders"][selectedLenderKey]["two_year"].stringValue
                let threeYear = swiftyJSON["lenders"][selectedLenderKey]["three_year"].stringValue
                let fourYear = swiftyJSON["lenders"][selectedLenderKey]["four_year"].stringValue
                let fiveYear = swiftyJSON["lenders"][selectedLenderKey]["five_year"].stringValue


                print(lenderName)
                print(oneYear)
                print(twoYear)
                print(threeYear)
                print(fourYear)
                print(fiveYear)

                fulfill({STRING})

            }

            catch{
                print("Error 2")
                reject({ERROR})
            }
        }

    }
    task.resume()
    }
}
```